# Static arguments to NLsolve.jl

Tags: julia

I am trying to use [NLsolve.jl](https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/NLsolve.jl) to solve a set of 6 equations with known Jacobian matrix.

The unknowns are in the array `U`, so following the repository example I created a function `fun!` as

```
function fun!(F, U, k)
   W = anotherFunction(U, k)

   F[1] = U[1] + 4*k[1]*U[4] - W[1]

   F[2] = U[2] - 4*k[2]*U[5] - W[2]

   F[3] = U[3] - 4*k[3]*U[6] - W[3]

   F[4] = U[1]*(U[4]*U[4]*U[4]*U[4]) - 
          U[2]*(U[5]*U[5]*U[5]*U[5]) - 
          U[3]*(U[6]*U[6]*U[6]*U[6])

   F[5] = k[7]*(U[4]*U[4]*k[4] - 1 ) -
         (k[8]*(U[5]*U[5]*k[5] - 1))

   F[6] = k[7]*(U[4]*U[4]*k[4] - 1 ) -
         (k[9]*(U[6]*U[6]*k[6] - 1))
end
```

where the values of `W` are computed throuhg another function. Similarly, the Jacobian reads

```
function jac!(J, U, k)
   J = eye(6)

   J[1,4] =  4*k[1]
   J[2,5] = -4*k[2]
   J[3,6] = -4*k[3]

   J[4,1] =  (U[4]*U[4]*U[4]*U[4])
   J[4,2] = -(U[5]*U[5]*U[5]*U[5])
   J[4,3] = -(U[6]*U[6]*U[6]*U[6])
   J[4,4] =  4*U[1]*(U[4]*U[4]*U[4])
   J[4,5] = -4*U[2]*(U[5]*U[5]*U[5])
   J[4,6] = -4*U[3]*(U[6]*U[6]*U[6])

   J[5,1] = 0.

   J[5,2] = 0.

   J[5,4] =  2*k[7]*U[4]*k[4]
   J[5,5] = -2*k[8]*U[5]*k[5]

   J[6,1] =  0.

   J[6,3] =  0.

   J[6,4] =  2*k[7]*U[4]*k[4]
   J[6,6] = -2*k[9]*U[6]*k[6]
end
```

The `k` array is constant and defined before calling `nlsove`, therefore I create two more functions to enclose `fun!` and `jac!` as described [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/looking-for-solvers-like-matlabs-fsolve-for-julia/4101/4), [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/solving-a-nonlinear-system-of-equations-in-julia/5261/2), and [here](https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/NLsolve.jl/issues/69)

```
f_closure!(U) = fun!(F, U, k)
j_closure!(U) = jac!(J, U, k)
```

However, calling `res = nlsolve(f_closure!, j_closure!, U)` results in this error

> ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching
>   (::#f_closure!#5{Array{Float64,1}})(::Array{Float64,1},
>   ::Array{Float64,1}) Closest candidates are:   f_closure!(::Any)

Is there a different way to pass the `k` array? Thanks!

Comment: Don't you need `f_closure!(F,U) = fun!(F, U, k)` instead?

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas it doesn't seem necessary. I tried that way and I got the same error

Comment: You won't get the same error because your error is saying `f_closure!` is a one argument method, and I gave you a two-argument method.